# Bootloader password - existing content found in /etc/grub.d/01_users

Tags: password, centos7, rhel7, grub2, boot-loader

I need to set a bootloader password and am apprehensive about changing the existing config (per warning about potentially making a system unbootable).

RH documentation says to [add the following lines](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-GRUB_2_Password_Protection.html):

```
cat <<EOF
set superusers="john"
password john johnspassword
EOF
```

The current `/etc/grub.d/01_users` file already has this at the top:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cat << EOF
if [ -f \${prefix}/user.cfg ]; then
  source \${prefix}/user.cfg
  if [ -n "\${GRUB2_PASSWORD}" ]; then
    set superusers="root"
    export superusers
    password_pbkdf2 root \${GRUB2_PASSWORD}
  fi
fi
EOF
```

Should I append the first part below the existing EOF, replace the existing content altogether, or something else?

Comment: It does say _at the end of the file_...

Comment: Just went through this in a test install of rhel7 in VirtualBox.  Replaced existing content in 01_users with the updated bit.   Rebuilt grub image and rebooted.  I have a boot loader password that works, and the systmem boots normally.

Comment: Both ways work (replacing and appending to end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `grub2-tools`, you will find `/usr/sbin/grub2-setpassword` in there. That is what the current contents are made for.

Running the `grub2-setpassword` binary will generate `/boot/grub2/user.cfg` containing:

```
GRUB2_PASSWORD=grub.pbkdf2.sha512.***
```

You can do this manually, just `cat /usr/sbin/grub2-setpassword` and see what actions to take. Basically run `/usr/bin/grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` and enter the content in the named `user.cfg` file.